# How to find sum of series $1+5+19+65+\dots + n$ terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find sum of series $1+5+19+65+ \dots + n$ terms?

Can't find any sequence.

Comment: This is not well defined.

Comment: Where is this sequence coming from?

Comment: @MichaelBurr i'm very very sorry.I made a typing error.Check now

Comment: @SanchayanDutta you haven't answered the question.  Where did you find this sequence?  Is it question from your class? Did you find it in a book?  Did you find it in a paper?

Comment: Looks like difference of powers of $3$ and powers of $2$? For $n\ge1$, I mean

Comment: @Arthur I think "can't find any sequence" means that he can't figure it out either, which led me to ask him where he came across this sequence in the first place.

Comment: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C5%2C19%2C65&language=english&go=Search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I did it.
[image]

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 1):

Recall the sum of the geometric series:
$$\sum_{k=0}^nr^k=\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$
If the sequence is indeed $a_n=3^n-2^n$, you can directly apply the formula above.